# VBA: creating many workbooks based on data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large data set in one worksheet `Sheet_1`. Data set is divided into many other data sets (there are some dividers in Excel like empty row or similar).

I have to collect data in this data set and create many new worksbooks based on data. For example,

```
COLA        COLB
Account #   Title
ACC1        12
ACC2        3
ACC2        3
----------------empty row divider ---------------
Account #   Title
ACC2        12
ACC3        3
ACC1        3
etc.
```

As a result I need a new worksheet for ACC1, for ACC2, for ACC3 and all other Account #. Actually, account number list is predefined in `Sheet_2`.

Will this algorithm fit my needs: 
1) get all necessary data for each account and save them wihin the same workbook, for example, in one sheet named "Results", where all data would be sorted by accounts

2) then using some loops or ranges or something creaate new workbooks for each account and copy/paste data there?

I am a programmer, but relativly new to VBA... so I am not sure that this is the algorithm that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strip out unwanted row dividers and rows with column headings, then sort the left overs so that col 1 has all the and only accountnumbers, then for next until the last row, creating workbooks and copying ranges, something like:

```
' TODO: Determine intLastRow
curAcc = ""
' TODO: Add target workbook to store rows to
For i = 1 to intLastRow
  If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) <> curAcc Then
    ' TODO: Save and close previous target workbook
    ' TODO: Add new target workbook
    curAcc = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
  End If
  ' TODO:Save active row from source workbook in target workbook
Next    
' Save and close last target workbook
```